# need msbuild task to combine app.config files

Tags: app-config, msbuild-task

Does anyone know how to combine app.config files into one
app.exe.config file?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us more data?

Anyway, If you use Tigris tasks Tigris is a custom library with useful additional tasks(http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org) you can use new task **Merge**

> **Merge**      Merge files into the destination file.

You might find useful (depending of what you need exactly) too **TemplateFile** Task that allows you to create a *app.exe.config* file from a template changing some internal variables.